# Email HTML template - getting the <a></a> tag to take full clickable width according parent <td>

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

**Email HTML template - getting the  tag to take full clickable width**

I'm having trouble finding a good way for rendering a full width `<a>` tag inside mail templates. The problem is that the `<a>` tag does not scale to the set `width`.

The link is only clickable on the text, and does not spread to the full width of the container. Even not when setting a fixed width.

Anybody have experience, or a good bulletproof snippet, for accomplishing this?

**Approach so far**

[image: A tag part]
The `display`or `width` property are not taken into account upon rendering of the email template.

I've tried (with several different adjustments) the following piece of HTML code. All without luck. It seems that for example Outlook does not take the `width` and `display` into account. The width keeps being set, to what seems, the same behaviour of `width:auto`.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
   <tbody>
      <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top;">
         <td align="center" valign="top" class=" padding-left-0  padding-right-0  padding-top-10  padding-bottom-0 " style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0; Margin: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.3; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="620" align="left" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 620px !important;">
               <tbody>
                  <tr align="center" width="620" style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 620px !important;">
                     <td valign="top" class=" padding-left-20  padding-right-20  padding-top-10  padding-bottom-10 " align="center" style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0; Margin: 0; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.3; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center; background: #ffc20f; color: #ffffff !important;">
                        <a bgcolor="#ffffff" href="ipsum" target="_blank" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; Margin: 0; line-height: 1.3; mso-style-priority: 99; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 0px; cursor: pointer; background: #ffc20f; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #ffc20f; width: 620px; text-align: center !important;display:inline-block;width:100%;"> 
                        <span style="color: #ffffff">IPSUM</span>
                        </a>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWKVPZ)

I've been looking around to find ways in accomplishing what i want to do, but no luck. I'm looking for a bulletproof cross-mail client solution.

Litmus has a topic on that, but that does not solve the problem. 
https://litmus.com/community/discussions/117-making-bulletproof-buttons-100-clickable

Comment: try this tag : `<a bgcolor="#ffffff" href="ipsum" target="_blank" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; Margin: 0;display:inline-block;width:100%; line-height: 1.3; mso-style-priority: 99; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 0px; cursor: pointer; background: #ffc20f; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #ffc20f; width: 620px; text-align: center !important;"> `

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the `display:inline-block;width:100%;` does not work either. I've tried it before :(

Comment: what about if you put a 100% div tag inside the <a> tag? :<a href="some link"> <div style="width:100%">link</div></a>

Comment: Width for `p` and `div` tags is not supported in outlook. So that won't work I'm afraid. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: and putting the <a> tag outside the <td> tag?

Comment: Tried wrapping extra `<a>` tags around the `<td>`, does not work either (Outlook / hotmail / Gmail)

Comment: sorry, out of ideas now :P

Comment: Try this: https://buttons.cm/ . You'll definitely need some conditional vml for outlook!

Comment: Unfortunately, VML kills link tracking. Not really an option to use `buttons.cm`

Comment: Isn't the tracking dependent on the Link not the calling code? With what do you track the Links?

Comment: It's our inhouse email campaigner, so all custom implementations. For now we have been rendering images for these kind of things. Because all elements can have paddings (content & spacing) / ....  Since we are porting our email template renderer to 'responsive' standards, we also have to change the way we render buttons to a CSS way. VML showed problems on link insertions (tracking actions) accross Outlook versions.

Comment: But is this a Problem with VML, your tracking Links or your ESP?

Comment: It's caused by VML on SOME ESP'S. Anyhow, without going there in depth, If I'm correct - you point out that there is no bulletproof solution besides rendering with VML? :)

Comment: If there were one, no one would be using vml anymore :/

Comment: have you tried using [Bulletproof Buttons](https://buttons.cm/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concepts within the Litmus link your referenced should work. Outlook *does* support `display: block;` and `width`, though box model support on inline tags (such as `<a href>` isn't great).

---

Here is a basic sample of a full-width, clickable button:

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="background: #ffc20f; text-align: center;">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #ffc20f; border: 10px solid #ffc20f; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;">
                <span style="color:#ffffff;">IPSUM</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

To get **Outlook 2013** displaying better, you can [conditionally](https://litmus.com/community/snippets/71-outlook-2013-targeting) add a bunch of `&nbsp;`'s to the `<a href>` to widen the button width:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #ffc20f; border: 10px solid #ffc20f; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;">
    <span style="color:#ffffff;"><!--[if mso 15]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->IPSUM<!--[if mso 15]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--></span>
</a>
```

Might be hard to get exactly 100% width, but you might get close without screwing things up too much in other clients.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately while testing, I notice that `Outlook` (2013) does not render the button's `<a></a>` link to the full width of the parent `<td>`. The link is only clickable for the width of the text.

Comment: @daan.desmedt I added an Outlook 2013 hack above.

Comment: Thanks Ted for you answer, I suppose this is the furthest we can get having support for public enemy Outlook :)

Comment: I've tried many solutions and the only one that worked is by adding a lot of  ```&nbsp```.

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the padding from the `<td>` containing it, and add the padding to the `<a>`.

Here's a [codepen fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWYLJq).

```
<td valign="top" class=" padding-left-20  padding-right-20  padding-top-10  padding-bottom-10 " align="center" style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0; Margin: 0; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.3; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center; background: #ffc20f; color: #ffffff !important;">
    <a bgcolor="#ffffff" href="ipsum" target="_blank" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; Margin: 0; line-height: 1.3; mso-style-priority: 99; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 0px; cursor: pointer; background: #ffc20f; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #ffc20f; width: 620px; text-align: center !important;display:inline-block;width:100%; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"> 
        <span style="color: #ffffff">IPSUM</span>
     </a>
</td>
```

Comment: We are talking about email design - Padding for p, div and a tags is not supported by Outlook. Thanks for the answer though, but your suggestion is not correct.